# Google Calendar API で予定の追加が行えない

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

pythonとGoogleAPIを用いてカレンダーに予定を入れたいのですが、下記エラーがでて登録ができません。
調べたのですが、解決せず解決策を教えていただきたいです。

**・コード**

```
#日付はバラバラにくる数字を日付に直して格納
dt_start = datetime.datetime('予定を入れる日時時間が入っている箇所(2021-06-06 11:00:00)')

dt_end = datetime.datetime('dt_startと同様に終了時間が入っている')

# Google にcalendarへのアクセストークンを要求してcredsに格納します。
creds = None

# 有効なトークンをすでに持っているかチェック（2回目以降の実行時に認証を省略するため） 
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
#期限切れのトークンを持っているかチェック（認証を省略するため）
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refreshtoken:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    # アクセストークンを要求
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # アクセストークン保存（2回目以降の実行時に認証を省略するため） 
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
    
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

body = {
    # 予定のタイトル
    'summary': '予定タイトル',
    # 予定の開始時刻
    'start': {
        'dateTime': str(dt_start),
        'timeZone': 'Japan'
    },
    # 予定の終了時刻
    'end': {
        'dateTime': str(dt_end),
        'timeZone': 'Japan'
    },
    'attendees': [ { email: "hogehoge@gmail.com"} ]
}

event = service.events().insert(calendarId='カレンダーID', body=body).execute()
```

**・エラーコード**

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId='カレンダーID', body=body).execute()
```

の部分でエラーになっています。

```
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not module
```

このエラーがでるためbody部分のdatetimeをstrで入れているのですが、それでもこのエラーが表示されてしまいます。
上のエラーは文字列以外に何か不足箇所があるのでしょうか。

とあるサイトでは変数ではなく直入力でしたが「2019-09-10T09:00:00」で記載しているようでした。
API周りに疎くご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: `{ email: "hogehoge@gmail.com"}`の`email`を`'`で囲んでいないからかも？ `{ 'email' : "hogehoge@gmail.com"}`を試してみては？ [Adding attendees with Google Calendar API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25333211/9014308)

Comment: 囲んで試してみたのですが
`
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Bad Request". 
Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}]">
`
が出てしまったので別途原因を探ってみるようにします。

Comment: 当初のエラーは解決されて進展があったが新たなエラーが発生したということで、いったんこの質問は自己回答等で終了して新たな質問を起こすか、おおもとの要求が満たされないので新たなエラーの状況を追記して質問を継続するか、してみてください。